# Add fragment on every page of A4 size Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, web, thymeleaf

I have requirement that a web page will have different section depending on the size of A4 sheet. For every section of A4 size, I need to have a confirmation check box.

How can I divide a webpage into smaller section of A4 size using thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use th:switch, th:fragment, th:replace tags to pull sections you need based on the input you provide.
Remember tho this would only occur on render by server thus real time would either need page reload or use javascripts to modify which sections are in and not.